# Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

Tags: jquery

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de obtener los valores de la URL. He hecho lo mismo con otras y me funciona correctamente, pero en esta URL no, no se el porque.

Código **JQuery**:

```
function listarURL() {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    });
  
    let conf = {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: headers,
    };
    return conf;
  }


  async function obtenerURL() {

    const GET_URL = 'https://dadesobertes.gva.es/dataset/38e6d3ac-fd77-413e-be72-aed7fa6f13c2/resource/a6ac1919-e2ab-4103-876d-4f4f54289955/download/covid-19-casos-confirmados-por-pcr-casos-pcr-en-los-ultimos-14-dias-y-personas-fallecidas-por-mu.csv';

    try {

      const resultado = await fetch(
        GET_URL,
        listarURL()
      );

      if (!resultado.ok) throw new Error(resultado.status);

      const json = await resultado.json();

      $.each(json, function(veces, valor) { 
        console.log(valor);
  });
      
    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
obtenerURL();
```

Las promesas y todo funcionan correctamente, porque ya la he utilizado en anteriores partes, pero en esta en específico, no se porque me devuelve ese error.
He mirado la documentación oficial sobre los fetch y se que hay distintos tipos de información que viene en una URL: String, Text... Como puedo obtener los datos sin que me devuelva el error?

Comment: La respuesta de esa url es un JSON?

Comment: Si la respuesta no es un JSON y estás usando `.json` te va a dar un error, prueba con `.text` y dinos si funciona

Comment: Siendo franco, tan solo viendo la URL (también realizando la consulta), se puede ver que el endpoint retorna un CSV, lo cual **jamás** será compatible con lo que espera `json()`.

Comment: Vale, entonces el formato `json` es inválido. Probaré con `.text`.